# Count the numbers of swaps in mergesort alogorithm in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I have the mergesort algorithm in c++ from geeksforgeeks.org, I'm trying to count the numbers of swaps on the arrays before the final array is sorted. I have got the idea of mesgesorting, but I found the mergesort algorithm kinda frustrating!

The code is this:

```
// Merge Sort
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// This function Merges two subarrays
// First subarray is stored in arr[l..m]
// Second subarray is stored in arr[m+1..r]
int count = 0;

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;

    // Create temp arrays
    int L[n1], R[n2];

    // Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[]
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];

    // indexes initialization
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = l;

    // merges the subarrays
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            count++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            count++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
        //count++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
        //count++;
    }
}
 
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
    if (l >= r) {
        return;
    }
    int m = (l + r - 1) / 2;
    mergeSort(arr, l, m);
    mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);
    merge(arr, l, m, r);
}

// main code

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 7, 4, 45, 67, 83, 90, 18, 2, 11, 8, 6, 18, 9, 15, 23, 5 };
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    // print given aray
    cout << "Given array is \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1);

    // print sorted array
    cout << "\nSorted array is \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << "\nThe numbers of swaps for the sorted array are " << count;
}
```

I've tried it also with an array but I did not get the result that I expected.
Does anyone have any idea about where am I wrong?

p.s.

`{ 7, 4, 45, 67, 83, 90, 18, 2, 11, 8, 6, 18, 9, 15, 23, 5}`
65 inversions

`{2, 11, 8, 6, 18, 9, 15, 23, 5, 7, 4, 45, 67, 83, 90, 18 }`
33 inversions

Comment: Merge sort is pretty simple, it boils down to recursive swap. I think you should first understand how it exactly works on paper and then just debug your code, using breakpoints.

Comment: I saw a video on youtue that make it much clearer. But still cant find the solution to my problem with counter. @MichałKaczorowski

Comment: Try debug your code. Setup few breakpoints, mock very simple and predictable input array to sort and go step by step, through sorting and merging. What IDE do you use?

Comment: I' m using codeblocks. My teacher gave me the code above and told me that the only change that I can make is to add my own code not to change the initial.

Comment: Btw thanks for your insterest...

Comment: I strongly recommend ditching code::blocks. For Windows, Visual Studio is way better and it's free. From there you can setup breakpoints in your code (F9) and debug as I said earlier.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for an intro here. Concerning your question, it's not ever clear what that is. Please state clearly what you expect and what you get. Before though, reduce your problem as far as possible to get a [mcve] and format your code consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution:

What you need to add is this:

```
 void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{

 int n1 = m - l + 1;
 int n2 = r - m;

 // Create temp arrays
 int L[n1], R[n2];

// Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[]
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    L[i] = arr[l + i];
for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];



// indexes initialization
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = l;

// merges the subarrays
while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
    if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;

    }
    else {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        count+=n1-i;
    }
    k++;

}
```